# Manual k-fold cross validation for Random Forest

Tags: python, random-forest, cross-validation, k-fold

I am using a Random Forest Classifier and I want to perform k-fold cross validation.
My dataset is already split in 10 different subsets, so I'd like to use them to do k-fold cross validation, without using automatic functions that randomly split the dataset.
Is it possible in Python?

Random Forest doesn't have the partial_fit() method, so I can't do an incremental fit.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. However, there is infinite number of ways to do that, which makes answering this question impossible, within reason.

Comment: Is your question about k-fold or a partial_fit algorithm

Comment: you can fold based on a timestamp

Comment: What does `partial_fit()` or other splitting functions have to do here? Do you have any *specific* difficulty in running a `for` loop, and in each iteration fitting to the (concatenated) 9 subsets while testing in the remaining one? If yes, please post what you have tried so far and the *specific* issues encountered. Otherwise, as @BartoszKP has already noticed, the answer to your question is simply "*yes, it is possible*" (and it has nothing to do with Random Forest in particular, or any other specific algorithm whatsoever).

Answer (score 0):

try kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=123)   to evenly split your data

try kf=TimeSeriesSpit(n_splits=5) to split by time stamp
try  kf = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=123, shuffle=True) to shuffle your training data before splitting.

```
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(bryant_shots):
     cv_train, cv_test = df.iloc[train_index], df.iloc[test_index]

     #fit the classifier
```

you can also stratefy by groupings or categories and get mean averages for these groupings using kfold. It is super powerful for understanding your data.

Comment: k-fold purpose is to validate that your model is not overfitting your data and that it is not bias.   run tests for overfitting and bias by examining the coefficients.  Let me know if you need help doing that

Answer (score 0):

It is best to join all subsets and then split them for k-fold but here is the other way:

```py
for in range(10):
   model = what_model_you_want
   model.fit(dataset.drop(i_th_subset))
   prediction = model.predict(i_th_subset)
   test_result = compute_accuracy(i_th_subset.target, prediction)
```